# Unrecognized options "gaufrette" under "vich_uploader"

Tags: php, linux, symfony, vichuploaderbundle

I got following error when I update the composer.phar...

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]
 Unrecognized options "gaufrette" under "vich_uploader"



 Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception



[RuntimeException]
 An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command.
```

Here is my Vich Uploader Configuration

```
   vich_uploader:
   db_driver: orm
    gaufrette: true
    storage: vich_uploader.storage.gaufrette
```

and i got this error...

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]
 Unrecognized options "gaufrette" under "vich_uploader"
```

please let me know why it happened?

Comment: please post your vich_uploader in the config.yml files

Answer (score 4):

Check the indentation of your config.yml, the options "gaufrette" is not under "vich_uploader"
 but as storage value, as example:

```
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm
    storage:   gaufrette
```

[See the doc](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/storage/gaufrette.md#configuration) for further details

hope this help

Comment: ok, i edit your question with your configuration. Try removing the `gaufrette:true`from the config in accordion with the [doc](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/storage/gaufrette.md#configuration)

Comment: always view the `gaufrette`key? have you remove correctly?